# Check if an variable contains specific numbers

Tags: c++, math

I made an program to solve the formula {f(y) = area/y} that calculates the height and width [X and Y] of an rectangle to case it to have a specific area, and in the same time, the hight and weidth have a specific ratio between them {1.0539435519260202716443150560307}.

the program applies a range of numbers [Xmin,Xmax] on the formula for Y and print out Y,X and the X/Y ratio in one line, and the loop increases the number that will be applied by a "step" every time the loop ends.

so the problem is that in order to find the most accurate ratio (the nearest to the one i need), I need to make the step too small, but this gives me thousands of results, which is impossible for me to manually search for it, so I wanted the program to only print the lines that have the ratio that at least includes the numbers {1.053} so that iam sure that it's too near the original ratio that I want, I tried searching alot, but it seems all the available methods out there is for strings only, so can someone suggest me a workaround/logic or even a whole different way to do this? Plus that I tried vb.net language, but it's the same, it only applies for strings.

Here's the code :-

(The variable declaration didn't get highlighted by stackoverflow, so i removed it, but i set "double" data type for the four vars).

```
cout << "Enter Area" << endl;
cin >> area;
cout << "Enter Xmin" << endl;
cin >> Xmin;
cout << "Enter Xmax" << endl;
cin >> Xmax;
cout << "Enter Step" << endl;
cin >> step;

double x, y, multi, ratio;

for (double i = Xmin; i <= Xmax; i += step)
{
    x = i;
    y = area / x;
    multi = x * y;
    ratio = x / y;

    cout << "y = " << y << "     X = " << x << "     Ratio  =  " << ratio << endl;

}
system("pause");
```

And there is no way for this, is there other programming language that supports this simple task?

Comment: You seem a bit confused. What's your *actual* question?

Comment: "The variable declaration didn't get highlighted by stackoverflow" - So? Why does that matter?

Comment: It's difficult to follow your question. Do you want to see how close is a number to a specific ratio? I.e. is this what you want: `if (std::abs(ratio - 1.0539435519260202716443150560307) <= 0.0001)` ?

Comment: This iterative approach is completely wrong. No iterative approach is required, when the exact formula is pretty simple. If the width to height is a specific ratio `R`, then the area is `A= n * (n*R)`, width times height. Solving for `n` is trivial, high-school level algebra. The solution here should be just one or two lines of code, and not this entire novel.

Comment: C++ and almost all other programming languages are Turing complete, which means you can use them to compute any algorithm. There are probably languages out there specifically designed to make complex mathematical and scientific computations easy which have existing facilities to do this, but for a simple task like this, you're much better off getting your algorithm right than learning some new language.

Comment: If your step size is small enough, you can still get thousands of results where `abs(ratio - 1.053) < 0.0005)` (or whatever epsilon you decide you want). I would step back a moment and ask why are you manually searching for the best result instead of having the computer do it for you?

Comment: @JaMiT actually my question is how I make the computer do it to me

Comment: @JesperJuhl I think i had to follow the rules so i stop getting down votes

Comment: @AhmedAhmedEG Right now your question asks how to "only print the lines that have the ratio that at least includes the numbers {1.053}". If you meant to ask a different question, please edit your question to ask what you intended. (Having the computer search for the best result would amount to printing the *single* line that is closest to the desired ratio, not printing all lines that happen to be within some small error amount.)

Comment: @bolov I want it to print only the lines that the ratio value on it is too near to 1.0539435519260202716443150560307 so i thought about searching all ratio values in every line for the first 4 digits which is 1.053 so then iam will be sure that this ratio is too near to 1.0539435519260202716443150560307 because its starts with the same 4 digits

Comment: And although i keeped my grammer corrct, and formated the question correctly, i still getting down votes

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you are right, and Alexander's way is better too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const double requestedRatio = 1.0539435519260202716443150560307;

while(Xmax - Xmin >= 0.00000000001)
{
    x = (Xmax + Xmin) * 0.5;
    y = area / x;
    multi = x * y;
    ratio = x / y;

    if (ratio < requestedRatio) Xmin = x;
    else Xmax = x;
}    
cout << "y = " << y << "     X = " << x << "     Ratio  =  " << ratio << endl;
```

This is classic binary search. You start with search range `Xmin:Xmax`. Divide it in half and pick the part, that is "closer" to your expected result, than the other. As a result you can find `x` as close to your required ratio as you wish - just modify `while` condition.

Comment: Thanks alot for this code, Alexander simplified the formula alot, but this code will help alot with similar situation that i will need to search for specific numbers in an variable's value, I started to think that there is no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with some simple algebra:

We have `x * y = area`, and `x / y = ratio`. There are a couple of ways you can solve this system of equations, such as multiplying the two equations which give you `x^2 = area * ratio`. So `x = sqrt(area * ratio)`. Dividing the two equations give `y^2 = area / ratio`, so `y = sqrt(area / ratio)`.